# NodeJS crypto package with zip files

Tags: node.js

I'm following the encryption example on this URL (code sample below) (http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/). The problem is that I'm encrypting a `.zip` file, which seems to work just fine. The decryption is the problem. If I perform the code example below on something like a `jpg`, the picture comes out just fine. But if I run a zip file through it and I try to `unzip` the result, I get the following error:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

Code:

```
// Nodejs encryption of buffers
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
    password = 'd6F3Efeq';

var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

// input file
var r = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
// zip content
var zip = zlib.createGzip();
// encrypt content
var encrypt = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
// decrypt content
var decrypt = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password)
// unzip content
var unzip = zlib.createGunzip();
// write file
var w = fs.createWriteStream('file.out.txt');

// start pipe
r.pipe(zip).pipe(encrypt).pipe(decrypt).pipe(unzip).pipe(w);
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the difference in my code was it was reading from a request stream. Apparently you can't just pipe a request stream through gunzip through decryption? I'm not sure why.

But if I same the stream to a file and THEN run it through gunzip and decryption it works.

If anyone has any input as to why, I'd at least like to understand!